# Where can I find Portal 2 mods?

Tags: steam, portal-2, mods

I obviously don't own Portal 2 yet but am considering buying since it's on sale on Steam at the moment. My question is - I've heard that the SDK has been released some weeks ago so one would expect some custom maps already available. However I cannot find one reliable website with mods and maps. Where can you get them from? Are they available from within the game instead?

Comment: Mods are not available from within the game. You'll have to search the Web.

Comment: Thanks Pyro. Can you recommend a reliable resource please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Gamefront](http://www.gamefront.com/top-10-portal-2-mods/) has made a list of 10 nice mods for Portal 2 and [My Aperture Labs](http://www.myaperturelabs.com/) provides many mods and maps for Portal 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks. Is that the only one? Isn't there one resource for all mods?

Comment: @Tomas I added My Aperture Labs link to the answer!

Answer (score 6):

On of the best sites for maps and mods is [ThinkingWithPortals.com](http://www.thinkingwithportals.com/). Consider that at the moment there are few mods because the SDK has been just released and modders need time to create something different, but there are available already [many maps](http://forums.thinkingwithportals.com/downloads.php).

They announced a couple of weeks ago winners of [Summer Mapping Initiative](http://forums.thinkingwithportals.com/newspost-t3751.html), a contest for map makers that had a lot of entries:

> Over the course of the past two and some change weeks, our 13 judges
>   have spent over a collective 140 hours playing 240 of some of the best
>   custom maps this community has seen. As I have said previously, the
>   turn out for this contest has been amazing and I want to thank each
>   and every one of our participants.

In addition you can find also something at [Mod DB](http://www.moddb.com/mods?filter=t&kw=Search%20...&released=def&style=def&theme=def&game=12617&type=def).

Answer (score 1):

There are no "mods" for Portal 2. There are maps, map packs, texture and model replacements, but no actual mods in the typical sense of the term as the source for Portal 2 is not part of the SDK.

Comment: That's simply not true. There are complete games based on Portal, like Prelude.

Comment: Prelude is not a mod, it is a map pack. Yes, it sits in the sourcemods directory and yes it has its own shortcut in steam but it uses the _exact same build of Source as Portal_ (it actually just mounts itself in Portal). In this respect (as in, modifying the game's source code), it cannot be considered a source mod.

Comment: So by your definition, it isn't a mod. By the definition of Steam, it is. I wonder which is more authoritative.